# determine all branching points and the branching structure of $f(z)=\frac{z^3+3z^2-2z+1}{z^2(z+1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{P}^1$ deonte the Riemann sphere. Consider the covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$ by $\mathbb{P}^1$ determined by the function 
$f(z)=\frac{z^3+3z^2-2z+1}{z^2(z+1)^2}$. How can we determine all branching points and the branching structure? Thanks!

Comment: Well you could start by picking a random complex number $k$ and see how many numbers $z$ satisfy $f(z)=k$ ?

Comment: Well, branching points happen when $f(z)=k$ has roots with high multiplicity, maybe you can look at some discriminant.